# Trying to Scrape Div Class

Tags: r

I am trying to scrape the div class of one site, I believe, or perhaps it is the div id.  Anyway, I am trying to grab the data for each dentist from the link below.

https://www.healthgrades.com/usearch?what=Dentistry&where=Canal%20Street%2C%20NY%2010013&pt=40.720901%2C%20-74.008904&pageNum=2&neCorner=40.73066740706064%2C-73.99139615546807&swCorner=40.711097020397304%2C-74.02644835278574&mapCenter=40.720901%2C-74.008904&zoomLevel=14.6&mapChanged=false&city=Canal%20Street&state=NY&zip=10013

Here is my code sample.

```
library(rvest)

URL <- "https://www.healthgrades.com/usearch?what=Dentistry&where=Canal%20Street%2C%20NY%2010013&pt=40.720901%2C%20-74.008904&pageNum=2&neCorner=40.73066740706064%2C-73.99139615546807&swCorner=40.711097020397304%2C-74.02644835278574&mapCenter=40.720901%2C-74.008904&zoomLevel=14.6&mapChanged=false&city=Canal%20Street&state=NY&zip=10013"

scistarter_html <- read_html(URL)
scistarter_html

scistarter_html %>%
  html_nodes("a") %>%
  head()

scistarter_html %>%
  html_nodes("div") %>%
  head()
```

That gives me this, which seems fine.

```
{xml_nodeset (6)}
[1] <div class="outofpage"><div id="div-gpt-ad-outofpage-oop"></div></div>
[2] <div id="div-gpt-ad-outofpage-oop"></div>
[3] <div class="hgGlobalHeader__Search" data-reactid="14">\n<label for="hgGlobalHea ...
[4] <div class="hgGlobalHeader__SearchForm" data-reactid="18"><div class="autosugge ...
[5] <div class="autosuggest-rex autosuggest-rex--header  autosuggest-rex--loading " ...
[6] <div class="autosuggest " data-reactid="28">\n<div class="autosuggest__header-c ...
```

This next line of code doesn't seem to work at all.

```
scistarter_html %>%
  html_nodes("div#card-carousel-search") %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>%
  html_table() %>%
  "["(1) %>% str()


List of 1
 $ : NULL
```

Again, I am trying to scrape the data from this id.

```
<div class="card-carousel  " id="card-carousel-search">
```

At least, that's what I think it should be.
I am following the example from here.

https://rpubs.com/ryanthomas/webscraping-with-rvest

Comment: I don't think there's a table node. The content seems to be generated dynamically, in which case you won't get far with rvest

Comment: This activity violates the site's [`robots.txt`](https://www.healthgrades.com/robots.txt) technical control and puts anyone who helps at risk of civil action at least in the U.S.

Comment: oh, I didn't realize that.  Ok, I'm just trying to learn the concept.  Is there another, similar but different, example to learn from out there somewhere?